# VBA + Selenium keep open Edge browser after test

Tags: excel, vba, selenium

Currently I use selenium webdriver to login to a website and send text with VBA macro. The problem is that at the end of the macro the browser closes. Is there a way to keep open edge browser after the macro is finished?

Any help is appreciated.

Selenium basic 2.0
Windows 10
Excel 2010
Edge browser

This is my code:

```
Sub Repsol()

Dim driver As New WebDriver
Set driver = New EdgeDriver
With driver

.Start "edge"
.Get "https://login.repsol.com/es/Landing/AuthnPage?returnUrl=https://www.repsol.com/es_es/"

 With .FindElementByClass("gigya-login-form")

        .FindElementByClass("gigya-input-text").SendKeys "user" 'your user
        .FindElementByClass("gigya-input-password").SendKeys "password" 'your password
         
         
         .FindElementByClass("gigya-input-submit").submit
End With

 Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 10)
 .Get "https://www.repsol.com/es_es/aplicaciones/SO/WebEESS/default.aspx?usuario="""
Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 10)

         
 .Get "https://www.repsol.com/SO/WebEESS/Pages/Carburantes/PeticionCarburante/Peticion.aspx"

 With .FindElementByClass("tablaContenedora")

        .FindElementById("ctl00_zona1_grdwCarburantes_ctl02_lbltxtCantidad").SendKeys [B7]

         End With
End With

End Sub
```

The macro works perfectly but the Edge browser closes when the routine ends

Comment: I believe the browser will close when the driver object is destroyed.

Comment: If you just need it kept open for verifying something during dev, you can always just stop the macro in its tracks and not let it finish the sub until you decide to - via a `MsgBox`, or even a `Stop` before the `End Sub`. This does not solve your problem, but it might delay it enough to help you at least somewhat.

Answer (score 1):

Add your declaration outside of your sub which will keep the window open:

```
Dim driver as WebDriver

Sub Repsol()

Set driver = New EdgeDriver
With driver

.Start "edge"
.Get "https://login.repsol.com/es/Landing/AuthnPage?returnUrl=https://www.repsol.com/es_es/"

 With .FindElementByClass("gigya-login-form")

        .FindElementByClass("gigya-input-text").SendKeys "user" 'your user
        .FindElementByClass("gigya-input-password").SendKeys "password" 'your password
         
         
         .FindElementByClass("gigya-input-submit").submit
End With

 Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 10)
 .Get "https://www.repsol.com/es_es/aplicaciones/SO/WebEESS/default.aspx?usuario="""
Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 10)

         
 .Get "https://www.repsol.com/SO/WebEESS/Pages/Carburantes/PeticionCarburante/Peticion.aspx"

 With .FindElementByClass("tablaContenedora")

        .FindElementById("ctl00_zona1_grdwCarburantes_ctl02_lbltxtCantidad").SendKeys [B7]

         End With
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In python you would run detach mode such as:

```
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
```

In VBA looks like it might be to use set preference?

```
driver.SetPreference "detach", True
```

Maybe?

Comment: Thanks DMart, Is there any way to do it without Python? I don't know about this tool and my code is based on Vba.

Comment: updated my comment, the 2nd one is the first attempt I'd try.

Comment: Sorry buddy, I didn't see your update.  I have added your instruction but it doesn't work.  when the macro finishes the browser closes.  any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public driver as New Selenium.EdgeDriver

sub

end sub
```

Comment: Hi my friend but it doesnt work :(, edge is going to close again.

Answer (score 0):

run your driver in global scope and it will stay open.
For example:

```
private driver As New WebDriver

sub Repsol()

...
end sub
```

alternatively you can add in manual wait times such as

```
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:20")
```